# Pub serve all files

Tags: dart, dart-pub

In terms of js/css/img type assets, is there a way to serve everything you have in "web" and "lib" regardless of whether or not you used it in your HTML?

Also, maybe put that small bit in bold in the documentation...It took me FOREVER to figure out pub serve only included files that were actually used in the HTML.

I tried the --all flag, but that didn't seem to work.

You may ask why? Because isn't it so awesome that Dart is so smart in that it only includes what you use? Well yea if it actually worked and was so simple that'd be great...But the problem is it while it parses the HTML and that's all well and good...Other JS files could themselves depend on assets. Pub serve doesn't go that deep. Plus, AJAX loading, etc. I just want all my assets. I put them there for a reason. I really dislike how Dart assumes certain things.

I suspect it has something to do with transformers and perhaps I could have my own...and I'm looking into that now, but is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: and for a real world example. try using an angular.dart project all built in some other dart project. angular uses partials, so you'll have html templates coming in asynchronously... they'll never load under pub serve because they won't be on the dev server.

Comment: If this is the case you should file a bug report in the Angular.dart Github repo.

Comment: it's not an angular.dart bug though. pub serve doesn't work in a way that's going to work for my workflow. i'm now using grunt to run a node.js dev server and pop up chromium. that seems to work much better than pub serve. and it has live reload.